# Python IMAPClient - how to group conversations from inbox/sent folders?

Tags: python, imap, dovecot, imapclient

I was able to group conversations for inbox for exmaple with:

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
mail = IMAPClient(domain, ssl=True)
mail.login(username+"@"+domain, password)
mail.select_folder(folder)
threads = mail.thread(algorithm='REFERENCES', criteria='ALL')
```

That works without error. 
Now I am having trouble grouping messages from inbox and sent. 
Lets say I received 4 messages (grouping works with previous code) and sent 3. That means I want to show 7 in total and not just 4 i have received.

I do not need a ready to use solution, just some suggestions on where to start. Thanks.

Comment: You would likely need to fetch and parse the References, In-Reply-To and Message-Id headers.  In `IMAP`, every folder is independent, and so thread will not give you information about threads across different folders.

Comment: If you are using Gmail, they have an extension where you can fetch the internal thread id, which does work across folders.

Comment: @Max I am not using gmail.

Comment: Then header parsing is the way to go. :)

Comment: @Max that will take some doing :)